# Messaging in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, messaging

I've been setting up a user to user messaging system using this rails tutorial http://www.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html

I know its pretty old but I haven't really had a problem tweaking it to work now. My only problem is that the inbox is not displaying and the error that appears is "Couldn't find Folder without an ID" I'm not sure what I should do. My code is pretty much the same, besides some tweaks, with the code in that link until right before reply. Thats where I stopped.

My Folder Model looks like

```
class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :messages, :class_name => "MessageCopy"
end
```

My Mailbox controller looks like

```
class MailboxController < ApplicationController

  def index
    redirect_to new_session_path and return unless signed_in?
    @folder = current_user.inbox
    show
    render :action => "show"
  end

  def show
    @folder ||= current_user.folders.find(params[:id])
    @messages = @folder.messages.paginate :per_page => 10, :page => params[:page], :include       => :message, :order => "messages.created_at DESC"
  end
end
```

If any other code needs to be included let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you call `show` from within the index action that @folder is not set and so it calls `current_user.folders.find(params[:id])` but because of the way you have called it `params[:id]` is nil.

This would cause an exception.

I suggest instead to change your index action to look like this:

```
def index
  redirect_to new_session_path and return unless signed_in?
  @folder = current_user.inbox
  redirect_to :action => :show, :id => @folder.id
end
```

Instead of rendering the show action from within the index action, just redirect to the show method with the correct id parameter.

Comment: When I do that it then comes up with the error "Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id"

Comment: So perhaps your `current_user.inbox` returns `nil`!

Comment: so what should I do to get it to work? I'm sorry if these are like simple questions I'm still a noob at all this.

Comment: You should set your current_user object correctly and keep it in the session scope, ie, exactly while you're logged in. 
Here's a tutorial I found very helpful when getting acquainted with sessions in Rails: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out#sec:sessions

This is available for both rails 2.3 and rails 3, the link is on that floating side-bar.